# GIT in eclipse: unable to push, after checking out an old version and change that

Tags: java, eclipse, git, push

I am using GIT in eclipse. I needed to checkout some older version, so I opened the history in eclipse and right click on the one I wanted and clicked "checkout". I applied the changes I wanted to make, and at the end I used GIT -> commit, and after inserting the description pressed "commit and push". However it said "There is nothing to push". The push button is inactive as well, and when I checked the bitbucket web page related to my source, this last commit is not recorded! what can I do to push this version into bitbucket?

Comment: It almost feels like you're working in a detached HEAD state.  Do you have the ability to drop down into a terminal and type `git status`?

Comment: I don't work with terminal, don't know how to work, but when I checkout some previous version, the header that was my branch name near my project name, changes to something else and I don't know how to push this to my branch again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a detached head situation. You have to create a temporary branch and merge this branch back.

This should do the trick:

```
git branch my-temporary-work
git checkout master
git merge my-temporary-work
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, it took time to find out how I can do this in eclipse. so now I have a temp branch which my last code is in it. How can I put that code in my main branch that I was working in now?

Comment: Checkout your main branch. Then merge in your temp branch.